# How to change type of Mongo DB property with the C# wrapper?

Tags: c#, mongodb

I'm using the 1.10 C# wrapper with Mongo DB.

I have this class:

```
public User
{
    public ObjectId SignatureImage;
}
```

and I changed the type of that same field to this:

```
public User
{
    public MyImageType SignatureImage;
}
```

And then I'm trying to get this deserializer to convert the stored ObjectId to the `MyImageType` type instead.

```
public class ImageRelationSerializer : BsonBaseSerializer
{
    public override object Deserialize(BsonReader bsonReader, Type nominalType, Type actualType, IBsonSerializationOptions options)
    {
        if (bsonReader.CurrentBsonType == BsonType.ObjectId)
        {
            var _id = bsonReader.ReadObjectId();
            return ImageAPI.Load(_id);
        }
    }

    public override void Serialize(BsonWriter bsonWriter, Type nominalType, object value, IBsonSerializationOptions options)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

I register the Serializer class with this:

```
BsonClassMap.RegisterClassMap<User>(cm =>
{
    cm.AutoMap();
    cm.GetMemberMap(x => x.SignatureImage).SetSerializer(new ImageRelationSerializer());
});
```

Then I run a `FindOneAs<User>` and the `Deserialize` executes as expected. But if it returns null, the 'FindOneAs' method throws an `Object reference not set to an instance of an object.` exception and if it returns an `MyImageType` then I get a `Specified cast is not valid`.

How do I solve this?